# Converting .cpp file to .wasm file

Tags: c++, webassembly, seal

I have a .cpp file that imports the microsoft seal library

`#include "seal/seal.h"`

it imports without any errors but when i try to convert the file to .wasm, i get an error saying

```
fatal error: 'seal/seal.h' file not found
#include "seal/seal.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I'm stuck. Does Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Important information is missing. For example: How do you convert it?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam i'm using emscripten

Comment: Use -I to add to the include search path, e.g.: `emcc main.c -I./SEAL/native/src`