# Error converting c++ file to wasm using emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten, webassembly, emsdk

This is a follow up question from this post [Converting .cpp file to .wasm file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729516/converting-cpp-file-to-wasm-file/58814579?noredirect=1#comment103907252_58814579)

I'm trying to convert my c++ file into .wasm using emscripten on linux. I'm running into this error:

```
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:188:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_readeflags_u32'
  return __builtin_ia32_readeflags_u32();
         ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:194:3: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_writeeflags_u32'
  __builtin_ia32_writeeflags_u32(__f);
  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:284:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_crc32qi'
  return __builtin_ia32_crc32qi(__C, __D);
         ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:305:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_crc32hi'
  return __builtin_ia32_crc32hi(__C, __D);
         ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:326:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_crc32si'
  return __builtin_ia32_crc32si(__C, __D);
         ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:354:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_rdpmc'
  return __builtin_ia32_rdpmc(__A);
         ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:360:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_rdtscp'
  return __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(__A);
         ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/ia32intrin.h:369:3: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_wbinvd'
  __builtin_ia32_wbinvd();
  ^
In file included from sealdemo.cpp:1:
In file included from SEAL/native/src/seal/seal.h:6:
In file included from SEAL/native/src/seal/biguint.h:9:
In file included from SEAL/native/src/seal/memorymanager.h:10:
In file included from SEAL/native/src/seal/util/defines.h:62:
In file included from SEAL/native/src/seal/util/clang.h:18:
In file included from /home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/x86intrin.h:15:
In file included from /home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/immintrin.h:14:
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:33:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:33:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:33:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:67:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:129:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:159:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:189:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:216:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:239:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:260:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:287:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
shared:ERROR: '/home/maria/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang++ -target wasm32-unknown-emscrip
```

Can someone help

Comment: ia32 says it all architectures are mixed up.

Comment: @Lee Sorry but can you explain it a little more ?

Comment: Regarding __builtin_ia32_* the documentation says:
"These built-in functions are available for the i386 and x86-64 family of computers, depending on the command-line switches used." but you are compiling to wasm so these functions are not supposed to exists in this context.

Comment: @Lee would you happen to know the workaround for this ? Do i forgo emscripten and use something else ? I'm a little lost.

Comment: I never used sealdemo.cpp but i think it best to start there or maybe some compiler flags where set. But you log don'T include information about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't include `x86intrin.h` when building for WebAssembly.  It looks like you need to build without `SEAL_USE_INTRIN`: https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/master/native/src/seal/util/clang.h#L18

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to compile the Microsoft SEAL library to WebAssembly using emscripten with intrinsics (`#include <wasm_simd128.h>`), but this is optional.

By itself, the toolchain never gave me this specific error as the `emcmake` step always wasn't able to find the necessary headers and compiled without the optimizations.

It sounds like you may not be using the appropriate `emcmake` or `em++` arguments. In addition, if you want to use intrinsics you will need some conditionals inside gcc.h and clang.h (located in SEAL/native/src/seal/util/) to use the `wasm_simd128.h` over `x86intrin.h`

Feel free to checkout my implementation and/or build scripts that compile on Mac and Linux (Ubuntu):
https://github.com/morfix-io/node-seal

Or download the npm package if you just want a working library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-seal